# laravel 5.1 ::lists() reorders keys

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Got a weird one here!

I've got a model Status with 5=>'Normal' and 10=>'Urgent'

```
Category::lists('status', 'id');
```

yields

```
Collection {#810 
  #items: array:2 [
    5 => "Normal"
    10 => "Urgent"
  ]
}
```

BUT

```
Category::lists('title', 'id')->prepend('');
```

yields

```
Collection {#810 
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => ""
    1 => "Normal"
    2 => "Urgent"
  ]
}
```

is this a bug??

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: just adding a blank top entry to use in a FORM::select
I could do this:
           $status = [0 => ''] + Status::lists('status','id')->toArray();
but it seems f-ugly

Comment: `Category::lists('title', 'id')->prepend();`?

Comment: You should read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: Michas: that's great only lists() returns a collection unless you convert it to an array. As usual, there's always a workaround, but what's the 'best laravel way' here.

Comment: aldrin27: prepend requires an argument

    Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::prepend()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jason Gilmore, author of Easy Laravel 5, "this is due to a recent change pertaining to the lists() method. No idea why but the Laravel developers decided to make it return a collection instead of an array."
Therefore,

```
$status = [0 => ''] + Status::lists('status','id')->toArray();
```

is the appropriate solution.